# No data is showing in object browser in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a SQL table created in Oracle database with 5 records. However, the records are not reflecting in the  Oracle Apex Object Browser (table). I tried refreshing the data but no luck.
I was able to insert the record from the object browser in APEX for time being.
Can you please let me know what may be the cause of data not being in sync in oracle DB and Oracle APEX?

[oracle database table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hajBP.png)

[Manually inserted the record from Oracle APEX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQF4q.png)

Comment: And while a commit could be your problem here, bare in mind that APEX & the DB are the same thing. APEX lives within the DB, and is executing queries in the same place, in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run **`commit`** statement then check Object Browser (Oracle Apex)

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot shows SQL Developer data. Looks like you didn't **COMMIT** after inserting those rows. Do so, then check what you see in Apex.